# How do I pass up (in the method stack) an Exception in Flutter?

Tags: exception, dart, flutter

I'm trying to make an REST app that uses "HTTP Get" communication to login in Flutter. While I had no problem importing "http/http.dart" package and
running the http class methods, I encountered a problem with exception handling in Dart/Flutter. I created a method to call http, but if
the connectivity is down for any reason, it will naturally return a "SocketException" exception. I have no problem handling the exception in the same method
who made the get request, but if I try to pass it up in the caller method stack to the parent method, I just can't catch it again. I found the
"rethrow" keyword, but so far, had no success in rethrowing the exception. Below are some methods I use in my code, both the login method and the caller method:

```
static Future<JsonEnvelop> loginUser(String email, String passwd) async {

    List<int> content = Utf8Encoder().convert(passwd);
    crypto.Digest digest = crypto.md5.convert(content);

    String url = _baseUrl + _loginUrl + email + "/" + digest.toString();

    http.Response response;
    try {
      response = await http.get(url);
    } on SocketException catch(e) {
      rethrow;
    }

    if(response != null && response.statusCode == 200) {
      return JsonEnvelop.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to login');
    }
  }

void onVerifyCodeBtnPressed(BuildContext context) {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      String email = _emailController.text;
      String passwd = _passwdController.text;

      Future<JsonEnvelop> envelop;
      try {
        envelop = RemoteUserServices.loginUser(
            email, passwd);
      } on SocketException {
        throw Exception('Internet is down');
      }
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Login to your account')));

      envelop.then((JsonEnvelop envelop) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: new Text("Login"),
              content: new Text("Login Successful"),
              actions: <Widget>[
                new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text("OK"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          }
        );
      });
    } else {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text("Missing data"),
            content: new Text("Type your email and password in the fields"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

What could be the problem in this situation? I hope to create a dialog box warning the user the internet is down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using rethrow or throwing a new exception. return a Future.error()

```
Future<bool> methodThatErrorsOnCall() {
 return Future.error();
}
...
...
methodThatErrorsOnCall.catchError((e) {
  print('I want to show a dialog: ${e.error}');     // callback fires.
  return false;                                     // Future completes with false
})
```

Comment: Thank you - was going crazy trying to figure out why try/catch wasn't working.

Answer (score 6):

`try`/`catch` with exceptions from async code works only in functions with `async`, otherwise you'd need to pass `onError` callbacks or use `.catchError(...)` on the returned `Future` which is notably more difficult to get right.

```
  void onVerifyCodeBtnPressed(BuildContext context) async { // added async 
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      String email = _emailController.text;
      String passwd = _passwdController.text;

      Future<JsonEnvelop> envelop;
      try {
        envelop = await RemoteUserServices.loginUser( // added `await`
            email, passwd);
      } on SocketException {
        throw Exception('Internet is down');
      }
```

Comment: When you await an asynchronous function, the execution of the code within the caller suspends while the async operation is executed. When the operation is completed, the value of what was awaited is contained within a Future object. So as a result, we can catch the thrown Exceptions in the sub-methods. Without await we don't wait either for a result or an exception.

Comment: @Patzu Actually, that you can catch has nothing to do with the Future holding the completion result. That you can use try/catch is because if you use async and await the code is rewritten by the compliler behind the scenes to support that. You could do the same without async/await and instead using `then()` and `catchError()` of the Future (as we did before async/await was supported in Dart).